# jquery autocomplete not working php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am posting this again as I couldn't get someone to help me out.
I have jquery autocomplete working fine with mysql, however I tried changing it to mysqli prepared statements but that doesn't work. Can someone point me out what is going wrong?

**MySQL:**

```
 <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("database");

 $term=$_GET["term"];

 $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products1 where title like '%".$term."%' order by id ");
 $json=array();

    while($student=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $student["title"],
                    'label'=>$student["title"]
                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

What I tried with MySQLi prepared statements:

```
<?php
$mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
$q = '%'.$_POST['term'].'%';
$stmt = $mydb->prepare(" SELECT * from products1 where title LIKE ? ");
echo $mydb->error;
$stmt->bind_param('s', $q);
$stmt->execute();
?>
<?php
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$json[]=array(
            'value'=> $student["title"],
            'label'=>$student["title"]
                             );


}
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change these lines

```
'value'=> $student["title"],
            'label'=>$student["title"]
```

to

```
'value'=> $row["title"],
            'label'=>$row["title"]
```

and you should be through

you are calling $student , whereas fetching in $row

Comment: wondering , in the code above you have $term=$_GET["term"]; and in the code below you have $q = '%'.$_POST['term'].'%';  , can you change $_POST to $_GET